# Hadoop 1.2.1 Eclipse Plugin problems with Eclipse kepler

Tags: hadoop, eclipse-plugin

I built the Hadoop 1.2.1 Eclipse plugin using the tutorial below. The build was successful, but when I copied my plugin in Eclipse and tried creating a new map/red proj in Eclipse, it gave me the error below. Can some one please help me in resolving the issue? This is driving me crazy.

> The selected wizard could not be started. Plug-in
>   org.apache.hadoop.eclipse was unable to load class
>   org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.NewMapReduceProjectWizard.
>   org.apache.hadoop.eclipse.NewMapReduceProjectWizard cannot be found by
>   org.apache.hadoop.eclipse_0.18.0

Tutorial:
http://ordinarygeek.me/2013/09/12/hadoop-build-and-install-hadoop-1-2-1-eclipse-plugin/

Comment: If you don't mind a newer 2.2 version, You can get a compiled version [here](https://github.com/abhishekgoel137/hadoop-eclipse-plugins). Then copy the jar, go to your eclipse install directory, and paste it to the `dropins` dir. That's it. Open Eclipse and you should be able to use it.

Comment: @peeskillet Thanks. I am actually looking to play around with the old version of Hadoop (1.2.1)